# R: Same Function With Different Outputs When evaluate in dplyr::mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am new to R and tidyverse. Now I encountered a problem:

Suppose we have the character "2-Jan-01":

When running the function, we get:

```
as.Date("2-Jan-01", tryFormats = c("%y-%b-%d", "%b-%y-%d"))

[1] "2002-01-01"
```

However, when I use the command mutate:

```
df %>%
mutate(birth_date=as.Date(as.character(birth),
tryFormats = c("%y-%b-%d", "%b-%y-%d")))
```

When converting the entry `2-Jan-01`, I get `NA` instead of `2002-01-01`.

I do not understand why the same function will evaluate to different values inside and outside of the mutate. Can anyone explain it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: And I assume `birth` is a character string equal to "2-Jan-01"? This seems to be implied, but then I don't know why you'd need to convert it to character... Can you share what `dput(birth)` outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine for me.

```
librayr(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  birth = "2-Jan-01"
)
```

Leaving your code untouched:

```
df %>%
  mutate(birth_date = as.Date(
    as.character(birth),
    tryFormats = c("%y-%b-%d", "%b-%y-%d")
  ))
```

I get:

```
  birth    birth_date
  <chr>    <date>    
1 2-Jan-01 2002-01-01
```

(Note that I used a tibble, but it works just the same with a traditional data frame).

Now, there is no reason to use `as.character()` in your code since "birth" is already of the class character. So removing it, we have:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    birth_date = as.Date(
      birth,
      tryFormats = c("%y-%b-%d", "%b-%y-%d")
    ))
```

Which gives the same result.

And if you don't want to keep the old "birth" column, you can use `transmute()` instead:

```
df %>%
  transmute(
    birth_date = as.Date(
      birth,
      tryFormats = c("%y-%b-%d", "%b-%y-%d")
    ))
```

Which gives:

```
  birth_date
  <date>    
1 2002-01-01
```